# Не импортируется библиотека foolbox

Tags: python, python-2.x

Код:

```
import foolbox
```

текст ошибки:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-4afca3d7469f> in <module>()
      2 #import numpy as np
      3 #from PIL import Image
----> 4 import foolbox

ImportError: No module named foolbox
```

Модуль `foolbox` установлен перед этим через windows power shell :

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> pip install foolbox
Installing collected packages: scipy, smmap2, gitdb2, GitPython, foolbox
Successfully installed GitPython-3.0.2 foolbox-1.8.0 gitdb2-2.0.5 scipy-1.3.1 smmap2-2.0.5
```

Запускал в jupyter notebook'е. Перезапускать jupyter пробовал - не помогло.

Почему библиотеку вроде бы установил, а в среде не видит?

Comment: Может, не в ту версию Python установили?

Comment: 3го питона не было, был только 2й, врятли не в ту версию